# Invert the action of an decorator in python

Tags: python, python-decorators, pyrogram

I'm working on Program, api application to python of telegram, in version 2, filter edited has replaced with a decorator of his own, `@clinet.on_edited_message`,
the problem is that I want to invert is action, and get only not edited messages, with filter is easy, add  `~` in the beginning, but how do I do that in a decorator? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Release Notes for Version 2 describe, `@app.on_edited_message()` only filters edited messages. If you want non-edited messages, use `@app.on_message()` instead.

Comment: in other words, using on_message will give me only edited message? just like ~edited?

Comment: @MenachemMinzberg `on_message` will only be NEW messages that have NOT been edited. `on_edited_message` will give you ONLY edited messages.